# rowMeans doesn't work on my data - all vectors are numeric

Tags: r

I need help on how to get one vector with the mean values of every row which results in the same length as the ones that are combined with the function.

I did this on the same data before with rowMeans (different subset but actually the same - I did though paste my way of getting to the subset as well). I created numeric vectors out of the dataset and now try to combine them but I always get the error:

> Error in rowMeans(subset(SME_partyA, select = c(ASvarchange1,
> ASvarchange2,  :    'x' must be numeric

I see other people pasting their console typings in here so I'm trying to paste mine.

```
dfs <- split(data_final, f = list(data_final$X__13, data_final$X__18))

SME_partyA <- rbind(dfs$`No.between 1 and 10 employees`,dfs$`No.between 11 and 50 employees`,dfs$`No.between 51 and 250 employees`)

ASvarchange1 <- as.numeric(SME_partyA$X__24)
ASvarchange2 <- as.numeric(SME_partyA$X__25)
ASvarchange3 <- as.numeric(SME_partyA$X__26)
ASvarchange4 <- as.numeric(SME_partyA$X__27)
ASvarchange3R <- car::recode(ASvarchange3, "0=10;1=9;2=8;3=7;4=6;5=5;6=4;7=3;8=2;9=1;10=0")

SME_partyA$ALChange <- rowMeans(subset(SME_partyA, select = c(ASvarchange1, ASvarchange2, ASvarchange3, ASvarchange4)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

> Error in rowMeans(subset(SME_partyA, select = c(ASvarchange1,
> ASvarchange2,  :
> 'x' must be numeric

Data:

```
dput(head(data_final))
structure(list(`2021-06-28-Rohdaten von Umfrage employer-and-employee-needs-in-the-home-office-environment (alle beendeten)` = c("ID", 
"166", "42", "161", "190", "217"), X__1 = c("Datum", "2021-05-19", 
"2021-03-26", "2021-05-19", "2021-05-19", "2021-05-19"), X__2 = c("Frage 1 - Please select your age group", 
"18-24 years", "18-24 years", "18-24 years", "18-24 years", "18-24 years"
), X__3 = c("Frage 2 - Please indicate which gender you belong to.", 
"male", "female", "male", "female", "male"), X__4 = c("Frage 3 - Do you have children living in the same household? - up to 3 years", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__5 = c("Frage 3 - Do you have children living in the same household? - between 4 and 6 years", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__6 = c("Frage 3 - Do you have children living in the same household? - between 7 and 9 years", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__7 = c("Frage 3 - Do you have children living in the same household? - between 10 and 12 years", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__8 = c("Frage 3 - Do you have children living in the same household? - between 13 an 15 years", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__9 = c("Frage 3 - Do you have children living in the same household? - between 16 and 18 years", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__10 = c("Frage 3 - Do you have children living in the same household? - older than 18 years", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__11 = c("Frage 4 - What is your current employment status?", 
"Apprentice", "Apprentice", "Apprentice", "Apprentice", "Apprentice"
), X__12 = c("Frage 5 - Are you employed by a company alongside being a student?", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__13 = c("Frage 6 - Do you have managerial responsibility in your current job?", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), X__14 = c("Frage 7 - For how many years have you been carrying out your current occupation?", 
"0-5 years", "0-5 years", "0-5 years", "0-5 years", "0-5 years"
), X__15 = c("Frage 8 - How many years ago did you start your professional career?", 
"0-5 years ago", "6-10 years ago", "0-5 years ago", "0-5 years ago", 
"0-5 years ago"), X__16 = c("Frage 9 - For how many years have you been working for your current employer?", 
"0-5 years", "0-5 years", "0-5 years", "0-5 years", "0-5 years"
), X__17 = c("Frage 10 - How many years ago did you start your current business?", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__18 = c("Frage 11 - How many employees are employed by the company you are working at?", 
"more than 250 employees", "between 51 and 250 employees", "more than 250 employees", 
"more than 250 employees", "more than 250 employees"), X__19 = c("Frage 12 - Are you currently working from home?", 
"yes, I work particular days from home (since more than 6 weeks).", 
"yes, I've worked from home since more than 6 weeks.", "no, but I worked from home within the last 12 months. All in all it was more than 6 weeks.", 
"yes, I work particular days from home (since more than 6 weeks).", 
"yes, I work particular days from home (since more than 6 weeks)."
), X__20 = c("Frage 13 - Are your employees / certain employees currently working from home or did they work from home within the last months?", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__21 = c("Frage 14 - Is a member of your household currently working from home?", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"), X__22 = c("Frage 15 - Is it possible in your eyes to carry out your occupation from home?", 
"0", "0", "2", "1", "6"), X__23 = c("Frage 16 - Is it possible in your eyes for your employees to carry out their occupation from home?", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__24 = c("Frage 17 - After starting to work from home, I quickly got used to the new way of working.", 
"1", "5", "1", "0", "7"), X__25 = c("Frage 18 - In my eyes, change is a chance.", 
"0", "4", "1", "0", "2"), X__26 = c("Frage 19 - I like it when everything stays the way it is.", 
"0", "10", "9", "10", "2"), X__27 = c("Frage 20 - I have fun learning something new.", 
"3", "1", "0", "0", "3"), X__28 = c("Frage 21 - While working from home I am regularly in touch and have regular exchanges with my direct supervisor.", 
"1", "3", "5", "0", "2"), X__29 = c("Frage 22 - My supervisor motivating me improved since I've started working from home.", 
"5", "6", "5", "2", "8"), X__30 = c("Frage 23 - I enjoy my current job.", 
"2", "2", "0", "0", "7"), X__31 = c("Frage 24 - I am able to motivate myself very well.", 
"0", "6", "0", "0", "2"), X__32 = c("Frage 25 - Since I started working from home, I make less mistakes at work.", 
"2", "5", "5", "4", "7"), X__33 = c("Frage 26 - In my opinion, my performance while working from home is better than while working at the office.", 
"5", "7", "5", "5", "8"), X__34 = c("Frage 27 - Since I started working from home, I am better at achieving the goals me and my employer agreed on.", 
"5", "7", "5", "5", "8"), X__35 = c("Frage 28 - I am more diligent working from home compared to working in the office.", 
"2", "9", "5", "5", "10"), X__36 = c("Frage 29 - It usually takes longer for me to work on a task from home than if I completed it in the office", 
"5", "5", "2", "3", "2"), X__37 = c("Frage 30 - The longer processing time rather is reason to the fact that something / someone distracts me and that my manager has more difficulties at controlling me than to a slower internet connection etc.", 
"-2", "-2", "8", "6", "4"), X__38 = c("Frage 31 - Since it is more difficult for my manager to control my work from home, I also make less effort.", 
"7", "5", "8", "9", "5"), X__39 = c("Frage 32 - While working from home I only report to my manager about my work progress if he or she asks about or requests it.", 
"3", "0", "7", "1", "8"), X__40 = c("Frage 33 - When working from home, it is expected that one shall be reachable around the clock.", 
"6", "10", "2", "10", "10"), X__41 = c("Frage 34 - When working from home, I find it harder to stick to break times.", 
"1", "0", "1", "0", "3"), X__42 = c("Frage 35 - When working from home, I have shorter active working hours on average compared to when working in the office.", 
"7", "0", "3", "10", "2"), X__43 = c("Frage 36 - I am regularly in touch and have regular exchanges with my employees when they are working from home.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__44 = c("Frage 37 - When my employees work from home, I have to give more motivation to them in order for their performance to be comparable to them working in the office.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__45 = c("Frage 38 - I give more motivation to my employees more when they work from home.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__46 = c("Frage 39 - Since my employees have been working from home, they are better at achieving the goals they agreed on with me / the company.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__47 = c("Frage 40 - I know what my employees are working on when they are working from home.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__48 = c("Frage 41 - It is important to me to know what my employees are working on when they are working from home.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__49 = c("Frage 42 - I want my employees to actively report to me on their work progress when they work from home", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__50 = c("Frage 43 - Compared to working in the office, the time it takes my employees to complete similar tasks increased significantly.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__51 = c("Frage 44 - I expect my employees to be reachable around the clock when they are working from home.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__52 = c("Frage 45 - When working from home, my employees have shorter active working hours on average compared to when working in the office.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__53 = c("Frage 46 - What prevents you / your employer from you working from home? - 1.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__54 = c("Frage 46 - What prevents you / your employer from you working from home? - 2.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__55 = c("Frage 46 - What prevents you / your employer from you working from home? - 3.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__56 = c("Frage 46 - What prevents you / your employer from you working from home? - 4", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__57 = c("Frage 46 - What prevents you / your employer from you working from home? - 5", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__58 = c("Frage 47 - What prevents you / your employees from them working from home? - 1.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__59 = c("Frage 47 - What prevents you / your employees from them working from home? - 2.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__60 = c("Frage 47 - What prevents you / your employees from them working from home? - 3.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__61 = c("Frage 47 - What prevents you / your employees from them working from home? - 4.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__62 = c("Frage 47 - What prevents you / your employees from them working from home? - 5.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__63 = c("Frage 48 - Please imagine your employer allows you to work from home. Which 3 needs would most importantly be met for you beeing able to work from home? - 1.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__64 = c("Frage 48 - Please imagine your employer allows you to work from home. Which 3 needs would most importantly be met for you beeing able to work from home? - 2.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__65 = c("Frage 48 - Please imagine your employer allows you to work from home. Which 3 needs would most importantly be met for you beeing able to work from home? - 3.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__66 = c("Frage 49 - Please imagine you could allow your employees to work from home. Which 3 needs would most importantly be met for you to actually let your employees work from home? - 1.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__67 = c("Frage 49 - Please imagine you could allow your employees to work from home. Which 3 needs would most importantly be met for you to actually let your employees work from home? - 2.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__68 = c("Frage 49 - Please imagine you could allow your employees to work from home. Which 3 needs would most importantly be met for you to actually let your employees work from home? - 3.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__69 = c("Frage 50 - I use the following technical devices for my work at home. - Laptop / Computer / (Spalten 1-4)", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "Provided by my employer", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "Was already in my personal possession", 
"Was already in my personal possession"), X__70 = c("Frage 50 - I use the following technical devices for my work at home. - Second monitor / (Spalten 1-4)", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "I don't have / use this", 
"I don't have / use this", "Was already in my personal possession", 
"I don't have / use this"), X__71 = c("Frage 50 - I use the following technical devices for my work at home. - External keyboard / (Spalten 1-4)", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "I don't have / use this", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "Was already in my personal possession", 
"I don't have / use this"), X__72 = c("Frage 50 - I use the following technical devices for my work at home. - External mouse / (Spalten 1-4)", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "I don't have / use this", 
"I don't have / use this", "Was already in my personal possession", 
"I don't have / use this"), X__73 = c("Frage 50 - I use the following technical devices for my work at home. - Headphones / Headset / (Spalten 1-4)", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "Was already in my personal possession", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "Was already in my personal possession", 
"Was already in my personal possession"), X__74 = c("Frage 50 - I use the following technical devices for my work at home. - Phone / (Spalten 1-4)", 
"I don't have / use this", "Was already in my personal possession", 
"Was already in my personal possession", "Was already in my personal possession", 
"Was already in my personal possession"), X__75 = c("Frage 51 - I consider myself as technically skilled.", 
"0", "7", "0", "0", "0"), X__76 = c("Frage 52 - With the technical devices available to me, I can practice my profession from home without restrictions.", 
"2", "3", "3", "2", "8"), X__77 = c("Frage 53 - It's not a problem for me to use my private technical devices or purchase new devices for my work at home.", 
"5", "2", "9", "10", "10"), X__78 = c("Frage 54 - Work space", 
"Work space - a lockable room which is usually not used as an office (after work)", 
"Work space - a lockable room which is usually not used as an office (after work)", 
"Work space - a lockable room, which is primarily used as an office", 
"Work space - a lockable room which is usually not used as an office (after work)", 
"Work space - a lockable room which is usually not used as an office (after work)"
), X__79 = c("Frage 54 - Work place", "Work place - a table and a chair", 
"Work place - a table and a chair", "Work place - a desk and an office chair", 
"Work place - a desk and an office chair", "Work place - a desk and an office chair"
), X__80 = c("Frage 55 - Household members who are also in the apartment during my working hours or, if present, neighbors' noises do not bother me at work.", 
"7", "8", "8", "6", "0"), X__81 = c("Frage 56 - I can focus a lot worse while working from home than when working in the office.", 
"5", "2", "2", "5", "2"), X__82 = c("Frage 57 - When working in the office, I have a lot more contact with my colleagues than when working from home.", 
"0", "2", "0", "5", "0"), X__83 = c("Frage 58 - If I have any questions or there's a need to interact, I can reach my colleagues from the home office just as quickly as when working together in the office.", 
"5", "5", "10", "3", "10"), X__84 = c("Frage 59 - How often do team-internal meetings take place that are organised by your manager?", 
"once a week", "twice a week", "twice a week", "daily", "twice a week"
), X__85 = c("Frage 60 - How often would you wish for team-internal meetings that are organised by your manager taking place?", 
"once a week", "daily", "daily", "twice a week", "twice a week"
), X__86 = c("Frage 61 - I found the following from my employer to be particularly good / helpful when working from home or when switching from the office to the home office", 
NA, NA, NA, ".", NA), X__87 = c("Frage 62 - With the technical devices available to my employees, they can practice their profession from home without restrictions.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__88 = c("Frage 63 - I expect my employees to (also) use their private technical devices or purchase new devices for their work at home.", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__89 = c("Frage 64 - How often do team-internal meetings take place that are organised by you or other mangers?", 
"-2", "-2", "-2", "-2", "-2"), X__90 = c("Frage 65 - I found the following from my employees / one employee to be particularly good / exemplary when working from home or when switching from the office to the home office", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__91 = c("ist anonym", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1"), X__92 = c("abgeschlossen", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), X__93 = c("beendet", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), X__94 = c("Beantwortungsdauer (in s)", 
"358.48", "404.25", "428.38", "446.06", "453.82"), X__95 = c("Antwort-Quote", 
"0.6153999999999999", "0.6153999999999999", "0.6308", "0.6462", 
"0.6308"), X__96 = c("Attribut 1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__97 = c("Passwort", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__98 = c("Sprache", "de", "de", "de", "en", 
"de"), X__99 = c("Startzeit", "05/19/2021", "03/26/2021", "05/19/2021", 
"05/19/2021", "05/19/2021"), X__100 = c("Endzeit", "05/19/2021", 
"03/26/2021", "05/19/2021", "05/19/2021", "05/19/2021"), X__101 = c("Laufzeit", 
"00:05:58", "00:06:44", "00:07:08", "00:07:26", "00:07:33"), 
    X__102 = c("Dauer f<U+00FC>r Seite 1 (in s)", "14", "18", 
    "10", "6", "48"), X__103 = c("Dauer f<U+00FC>r Seite 2 (in s)", 
    "23", "29", "26", "21", "21"), X__104 = c("Dauer f<U+00FC>r Seite 3 (in s)", 
    "69", "78", "125", "75", "88"), X__105 = c("Dauer f<U+00FC>r Seite 4 (in s)", 
    "91", "110", "79", "172", "169"), X__106 = c("Dauer f<U+00FC>r Seite 5 (in s)", 
    "160", "167", "186", "171", "125"), X__107 = c("Dauer f<U+00FC>r Seite 6 (in s)", 
    "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So I tried this myself with another example and failed... Could anyone tell me where my mistake is?

> LargeCo_partyB1 <- rbind(dfs$`-2.more than 250 employees`,dfs$`Yes.more than 250 employees`)

> colsContB <- paste0('X__', 47:49)

> new_colsContB <- paste0('Bvarcont', seq_along(colsContB))

> LargeCo_partyB[new_colsContB] <- lapply(LargeCo_partyB)[colsContB], as.numeric)
> Error: unexpected ',' in "LargeCo_partyB[new_colsContB] <- lapply(LargeCo_partyB)[colsContB],"

> LargeCo_partyB$BLCont <- rowMeans(LargeCo_partyB[new_colsContB], na.rm = TRUE)
> Error: Columns `Bvarcont1`, `Bvarcont2`, `Bvarcont3` not found
> Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: Welcome. Can you please share your data.frame ``data_final`` by pasting the output of ``dput(data_final)`` or ``dput(head(data_final))`` (if it's a big data.frame) into the body of your question. I don't think we can help you otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! I feel like even this doesn't work, as it is a really big data.frame... this is the error I get. Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut.    Does it help, if I press enter in between?

Comment: Type in ``dput(head(data_final)`` and then paste the output into your original question (by hitting the edit button). Put 3 back ticks ` before and after the block of text.

Comment: Still getting the error :(

Comment: Can you create a pastebin link? https://pastebin.com

Comment: You don't have any numeric value in `data_final`(`str(data_final)`). I don't really understand the ASvarchange part, are you trying to convert data in `X_24` etc to numeric class inside `SMEpartyA` ? Because in the example subset, as `ASvarchange=4`, it selects the 4th column which contain gender "female" so it is normal you can't do `rowMeans` on this, so it is not clear what you want to do there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the changes should be done in the dataframe and not in individual vectors.

I have also tried to simplify the code a bit  -

```
cols <- paste0('X__', 24:27)
new_cols <- paste0('ASvarchange', seq_along(cols))

SME_partyA[new_cols] <-  lapply(SME_partyA[cols], as.numeric)

SME_partyA$ASvarchange3R <- car::recode(SME_partyA$ASvarchange3, 
                     "0=10;1=9;2=8;3=7;4=6;5=5;6=4;7=3;8=2;9=1;10=0")

SME_partyA$ALChange <- rowMeans(SME_partyA[new_cols], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Wow so this is awesome! Thank you so much! I just need to understand what you did there in order to reproduce it to all the other things I need.  I'll post my attempt to try this on something else. Could you try and tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: The key part is making changes **in** the dataframe. `ASvarchange1`, `ASvarchange2` are independent vectors and they are not changed in the dataframe.

Comment: could you have another look at what I just updated in the main post? Apparently I am not able to reproduce what you did... Thank you! Will definitely accept you answer :)

Comment: You have a typo. You closed the `lapply` bracket early. `LargeCo_partyB[new_colsContB] <- lapply(LargeCo_partyB[colsContB], as.numeric)`

Comment: Could you maybe help me (hopefully) one last time? You did 24:27 because I needed 24,25,26&27. How do I do this if I needed 24,25& 30?

Comment: In that case you can do `cols <- paste0('X__', c(24, 25, 30))`